# Tensorflow sporadically negative values with tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy

Tags: tensorflow, loss, sigmoid

I'm using an Inception-V4 model to do a multi-label classification with tensorflow. The model has an output dimension of 51 and my labels are either one or zero for these 51 classes. I did not modify the Inception-V4 any further.

In order to learn the multilabel classification, I use a sigmoid cross entropy loss by applying tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy. My logits are unscaled (no activation function) and my labels also look fine. The overall loss is computed via tf.losses.get_total_loss().

Now the whole system works and learns for many epochs without a problem. However, after about 15 to 20 epochs of learning, it sometimes produces negative loss values. At this time the loss is around 0.01 but sometimes drops down to -0.15 or even lower (I once saw -1). Furthermore, my model's accuracy also drops after these steps, so I think it's actually hurting it.

Does anyone have an idea what I could have done wrong? Has anyone experienced this before? What could I do?

I didn't include my code yet, because I think its just a simple Estimator pipeline and I directly take the logits and auxLogits of the inception_v4 and attach such a sigmoid cross entropy loss to both of them. But if the code would help, I can try shrinking it to add it here.

This is what the loss of the logits looks like:

[image: This is what the loss of the logits looks like]

Comment: did you solve this? getting the same issue

Comment: If I remember correctly, I had some bad images in the input data... however, I'm not sure any more. Sorry, totally forgot about this question.